# How to submit form witout click on submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi i want to submit form without clicking submit button how can i do this

Here is my form

```
<form name="frmUser" method="post" action="" id="from">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit">
</form>
```

**jquery**

```
<script>
$('#form').submit(function(){return true;});
</script>
```

How Can i get this

any help will be appreciated

Comment: When (on which action) do you want to submit the form? Or on page load?

Comment: self action is there

Comment: Your form id is 'from'. Probably want to fix that typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#form_id").keydown(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            $("#form_id").submit();
        }
    });

});
```

HTH

P.S. your form id in HTML is "from" but the reference in jquery is "form". Plz fix this beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
$('#form').trigger('submit')
```

Comment: did you fix your typo? in your markup you have ID "from" but it needs to be form